# Setting Xcode "deployment target" or "base SDK" to a "point oh one" (0.0.1) release

Tags: ios, xcode4.4, base-sdk

In Xcode 4.4.1 it is possible to set the deployment target to a "point one" release of [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), for example; 4.3 or 5.1.

[image: deployment target - Xcode]

However it doesn't seem possible to set it to a "point oh one" release, for example; 4.2.1 ro 5.1.1.

Is this possible? And if so how?

#### Update

Setting the Base SDK to a "point oh one" release does seem possible however:

[image: Base SDK - Xcode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value is the same one as on the Summary Screen of your target. There it's called "Deployment Target".
You can also set it project wide in the "Info" tab of the project settings.
[image]

You can simply type over the value in the box

This will result in a build settings like this:

[image]